# mysql query explode with two table join

Tags: php, mysql, implode

my sql query

```
SELECT 
    team.id,
    team.atitle,
    team.etitle,
    team.cup_id,
    team.logo,
    team.modarb,
    team.count_id,
    team.link AS tlink,
    country.atitle AS name,
    country.etitle AS ename,
    cup.id AS catid,
    cup.link,
    cup.description,
    cup.name AS cupname
    FROM cup LEFT JOIN team ON (cup.id IN (". implode(', ', 'team.cup_id') ."))
    LEFT JOIN country ON (country.id = team.count_id)
    where cup.id='5'
```

row team.cup_id look like this 5, 4, 3,
need know how to use implode in mysql query

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not show any research or effort into possible solutions.

Comment: Well you're trying to implode a string there. You may want to read this: http://ca2.php.net/implode

Comment: You are mixing PHP with mysql. They are at different execution levels, you can't merge them like that.

Comment: See normalisation

Answer (score 0):

You should fix your data structure so you are not storing lists of ids as a string.  Doing so is wrong, wrong, wrong:

- It is wrong to store numbers as strings.
- It is wrong to have ids in a table without properly declared foreign key references.
- It is wrong to store lists in a single column, when SQL offers a great method for storing lists:  a table.

Just in case you cannot fix the data structure, you can do:

```
FROM cup LEFT JOIN
     team
     ON find_in_set(cup.id, team.cup_id) > 0 LEFT JOIN
     country
     ON (country.id = team.count_id)
```

I only offer this as a stop-gap until you fix the data to be SQLish in form.